# I am using react-fast-marquee for a horizontal scroll animation, and I have added a scale effect to it

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, scroll

I have the following code, and it is working about 90% how I want it to, it scrolls right to left, and I added a check to see when the image has reached the center of the page it should scale the image up just a little bit for effect.

This works fine for the first 3 images, but when the loop completes index 0 and index 1 never scale.

I have tried to figure this out for a while and can't seem to determine why.

Here is a code sandbox to see it in action and to play with it

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/zen-tharp-zvdwyk

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```js
    import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
    import Marquee from "react-fast-marquee";
    import styled from "styled-components";
    
    const props = {
      Carousel: [
        { image: "/1.webp" },
        { image: "/2.webp" },
        { image: "/3.webp" },
        { image: "/4.webp" },
        { image: "/5.webp" },
      ],
    };
    
    function Gallery() {
      const [updateLoop, setUpdateLoop] = useState(false);
    
      const [centerImageIndex, setCenterImageIndex] = useState(null);
    
      const imgRef = useRef();
    
      const [imageWidth, setImageWidth] = useState(0);
    
      function isImageHorizontallyCentered(pageWidth, imageWidth, imageX) {
        // Calculate the expected X coordinate for the image to be centered
        const expectedX = (pageWidth - imageWidth) / 2;
    
        // Define a margin of error, if necessary (e.g., for rounding)
        const marginOfError = 10; // Adjust this value based on your requirements
    
        // Check if the actual X coordinate is within the expected range
        return Math.abs(imageX - expectedX) <= marginOfError;
      }
    
      const checkImagePosition = () => {
        const pageWidth = window.innerWidth;
    
        props.Carousel.forEach((item, index) => {
          const img = document.getElementById(`image-${index}`);
    
          const imageWidth = img.getBoundingClientRect().width;
          const rect = img.getBoundingClientRect();
          const imageX = rect.left + window.scrollX;
    
          const test = isImageHorizontallyCentered(pageWidth, imageWidth, imageX);
    
          console.log("test", test, "index", index);
    
          if (test) {
            setCenterImageIndex(index);
          }
        });
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const intervalId = setInterval(checkImagePosition, 100); // Check every 100ms
        return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <Container>
          <ImagesContainer>
            <Marquee speed={100} pauseOnHover>
              {props?.Carousel.map((listItem, index) => {
                const isCenter = index === centerImageIndex;
                return (
                  <ImageWrapper key={index} id={`image-${index}`} center={isCenter}>
                    <LazyImg ref={imgRef} loading="lazy" src={listItem.image} />
                  </ImageWrapper>
                );
              })}
            </Marquee>
          </ImagesContainer>
        </Container>
      );
    }
    
    
    const Container = styled.div`
      // width: 1200px;
      // margin: 0 auto;
      width: 100%;
    `;
    
    const Caption = styled.div`
      color: var(--Terrace-Gray-900, #282c25);
      letter-spacing: -0.32px;
      align-self: center;
      margin-top: 430px;
      white-space: nowrap;
    
      @media (max-width: 991px) {
        white-space: initial;
      }
    `;
    
    const SocialMediaText = styled.div`
      align-self: center;
      color: var(--Terrace-Neutral-Black, #000);
      text-align: center;
      letter-spacing: -2.24px;
      margin-top: 8px;
      font: 700 56px/114% Satoshi, sans-serif;
    
      @media (max-width: 991px) {
        max-width: 100%;
        font-size: 40px;
      }
    `;
    
    const ImagesContainer = styled.div`
      // border: 1px solid blue;
    `;
    
    const ImageWrapper = styled.div`
      // width: ${(props) => (props.center ? "800px" : "100px")};
      // width: 600px;
      transform: scale(${(props) => (props.center ? "1.1" : "1")});
      // border: 1px solid red;
      transition: transform 1s;
    `;
    
    const LazyImg = styled.img`
      width: 300px;
      border-radius: 50px;
      background: #e0e0e0;
      box-shadow: 20px 20px 60px #bebebe, -20px -20px 60px #ffffff;
      //write a drop shadow
    
      margin: 40px 40px;
    `;
    
    export default Gallery;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the way `react-fast-marquee` is implemented.

Imagine the original image row being `|1-2-3|-4-5`, and first three images are in view. Now this is how it works:

- It creates a copy of the items row, say `c1-c2-c3-c4-c5`.
- The copy row is attached to the first one from right.
  `|1-2-3|-4-5-c1-c2-c3-c4-c5`
- Then it moves both the rows towards right.
  `1-2-3-|4-5-c1|-c2-c3-c4-c5`
- The moment the first row gets out of the view from left, it resets both the rows to original position.
  `1-2-3-4-5-|c1-c2-c3|-c4-c5` -> `|1-2-3|-4-5-c1-c2-c3-c4-c5`
- and the cycle repeats

This is why the first few items(1-2) never reach center of the view, and only their duplicates(c1-c2) in the copy row reach the center position.

Solution would be to consider duplicate row items as well:

```js
const checkImagePosition = () => {
    const pageWidth = window.innerWidth;

    outer: for (let index = 0; index < props.Carousel.length; index++) {
      // narrow the following query further to avoid conflicts with other stuff on the page
      const images = document.querySelectorAll(`[id="image-${index}"`);

      for (const img of images) {
        const rect = img.getBoundingClientRect();
        const imageWidth = rect.width;
        const imageX = rect.left + window.scrollX;

        const test = isImageHorizontallyCentered(pageWidth, imageWidth, imageX);
        if (test) {
          setCenterImageIndex(index);
          // to improve the performance break the loops after we find the center image
          break outer;
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Here is the working demo: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/zen-onks-tktlkg?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A42%2C1-55%2C6

Note the first image has been marked with red background.